# Can my laptop run ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: system-installation

My laptop is Acer Aspire1 A111-31, 4GB DDR4 RAM, Operating System: Windows 10 Home 64-bit,  Processor: Intel(R) Celeron(R) N4000 CPU @ 1.10GHz (2 CPUs), ~1.1GHz,  Card name: Intel(R) UHD Graphics 600

Comment: Have had a few Acers and they worked okay.  Would suggest using Lubuntu or Xubuntu instead of regular Ubuntu.  Not sure but you might have a baytrail CPU, which has a known bug that freezes desktop.  For fix just google ubuntu baytrail if it happens to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Acer laptop is [certified by Ubuntu](https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/models?category=Laptop&vendors=Acer)

Nonetheless, it will almost certainly work just fine - you can try it out by [creating a Live USB](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview) and booting from that; that will essentially let you run Ubuntu from a USB stick, so you can test out all your hardware works fine without actually having to install the OS. Once you're happy it works, you can go ahead and install.